# using stating for sqlcommand.executescalar

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, using

I am using a `using` statement for validating a customer number.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(CUSTOMER_NO) FROM WEBSITE_CUSTOMERS WHERE UPPER(CUSTOMER_NO) = '" + strCustomer.Trim().ToUpper() + "';", connection))
    {
        int nExists = (int)cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();
        if (nExists > 0) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

This is code previously advised to me on stackoverflow for checking preexisting records... it works great, but I would like to know if there's a way that I can use a parameter with it for the customer number since this variable is entered through the form, I want to protect it from injection. Where would I create the parameter for `cmdCheck` when its in a `using` statement like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the parameter after you've initialized the command. A convenient method is [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx):

```
const string sql = @"SELECT 
                        COUNT(CUSTOMER_NO) 
                     FROM 
                        WEBSITE_CUSTOMERS 
                     WHERE 
                        UPPER(CUSTOMER_NO) = @CUSTOMER_NO;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTOMER_NO", strCustomer.Trim().ToUpper());
        connection.Open();
        int nExists = (int)cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();
        return nExists > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is where I would normally do it but I wasn't sure if you could still do that when the command was initialized in a `using` statement or not. My confusing to do it within the `()` brackets or the `{}` braces! 
Sorry if it seemed like a silly question, still learning c#!

Comment: Is there any particular advantage to creating the `const string` for the command instead of just writing the command in the `SqlCommand()` method?

Comment: @Stuart: The `const` is just to demonstrate that nothing in the sql-string needs to be mutable when using `parameters`. I always separate it from the command-constructor for reasons of readability. The query is now much better readable as opposed to your one-liner approach.